# Button to control Keypress event?

Tags: vb.net, keypress

I'm new to VB but learning lots as I go and from this site.  I have another dilemma that seems like a very easy solution but I'm having trouble, even through searching this site and Google.  I want to use a button on my form to hold down the shift key.  So when the button is clicked, the shift key is held down programmatically until the button is clicked again.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to catch a key press. If so, this will help:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, _ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.G Then
      DO SOMETHING 
end if
end sub
```

You can also use other things like:

```
My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown
```

This can be included as part of an `if` statement.

Example:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
me.hide
end sub
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't believe that is the solution to my problem.  I'm not trying to catch a key event.  I need to programmatically hold/set a key down when a user clicks a button on the screen.  More clearly, I am using a "Zoom In" control that requires a user to hold the Shift Key (activates the Zoom control) and then drag the mouse around what he/she wants to zoom into.  I want the user to be able to click the "Zoom In" button, which will hold the shift key down programmatically, so that all the user has to do then is drag the mouse, eliminating the need for the user to hold the Shift key.